# How can a template type be restricted to a base class excluding a subclass of this base class?

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have two classes `A` and `B`. `B` is derived from `A`. Now I try to use this classes in the template for a third class `C` with a template parameter `T`. This template should restrict `T` to all classes derived from `A` excluding `B` and all subclasses of `B`. I try the following way:

```
template <typename T = 
    std::enable_if<
        (std::is_base_of<A, T>::value)
        &&(!std::is_base_of<B, T>::value)>::type>
class C {};
```

This template can be compiled. But if I try to use it, for example, with `T = int`, the application also can be compiled. So it is also accepted as correct parameter value. How should it be done right?

Comment: When you pass a template parameter explicitly, the default value is ignored and no substitution failure can occur in it. You need *two* templateparameters for this to work. You pass one and SFINAE is done with the other.

Answer (score 4):

I think using `static_assert` instead of `std::enable_if` would be more clear, you could specify the error message by yourself.

```
template <typename T>
class C {
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value && !std::is_base_of<B, T>::value, 
                  "T must be classes derived from A excluding B and all subclasses of B.");
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ND8htsHsJOcbasQY)

If you want to stick to `std::enable_if`, you need to reserve the template parameter `T`, and add an additional template parameter using `std::enable_if`. Note that when the template arguments are specified explicitly, the default arguments won't take effect (to restrict types). e.g.

```
template <typename T, 
          typename std::enable_if<(std::is_base_of<A, T>::value)
                                   && (!std::is_base_of<B, T>::value)>::type* = nullptr>
class C {
};
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/BWtqVTmt8hCriDsP)

Answer (score 0):

Another way pass through template specialization

```
template <typename, typename = void>
class C;

template <typename T>
class C<T, std::enable_if_t<true == std::is_base_of_v<A, T>
                        && false == std::is_base_of_v<B, T>>>
 { };
```

Also this solution can't be "hijacked" explicating the second template parameter

```
C<B, void>  cb; // compilation error also explicating the second parameter
```